# Generating 'ASCII-art' banners with arrows

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, special-characters, ascii-art, banner

I recently discovered `figlet` which generates ASCII-art banners. Joy!

... but, alas, I want a banner with an arrow on it. Now...

```
$ figlet unicode → arrow
             _               _         //\                                 
 _   _ _ __ (_) ___ ___   __| | ___   |/_\|    __ _ _ __ _ __ _____      __
| | | | '_ \| |/ __/ _ \ / _` |/ _ \  / _` |  / _` | '__| '__/ _ \ \ /\ / /
| |_| | | | | | (_| (_) | (_| |  __/ | (_| | | (_| | |  | | | (_) \ V  V / 
 \__,_|_| |_|_|\___\___/ \__,_|\___|  \__,_|  \__,_|_|  |_|  \___/ \_/\_/
```

isn't what I want, and

```
$ figlet -- unicode "->" arrow
 _                            _                      __                                 
| |___      _____         ___| |__   __ _ _ __       \ \    __ _ _ __ _ __ _____      __
| __\ \ /\ / / _ \ _____ / __| '_ \ / _` | '__|  _____\ \  / _` | '__| '__/ _ \ \ /\ / /
| |_ \ V  V / (_) |_____| (__| | | | (_| | |    |_____/ / | (_| | |  | | | (_) \ V  V / 
 \__| \_/\_/ \___/       \___|_| |_|\__,_|_|         /_/   \__,_|_|  |_|  \___/ \_/\_/
```

Doesn't quite cut it. I went to the man page, which mentioned fonts corresponding to different charsets - but those seem to add support for different languages, not arrows. What should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/kristopolous/UniFig claims to be a Unicode expansion of Figlet.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: If you look [through the bells and whistles](https://github.com/kristopolous/UniFig/blob/master/figlet.php), you'll find it basically does `exec("/usr/bin/figlet -w $width -f $font $text", $output);`

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.  Though it makes me happy I said it "claims to be" rather than "appears to be".